# Find height for a set of floating divs as if it were a single div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a selection of floating divs what is the height of only the set A-G as if the height of A-G were a single div?

Example positions depend on width of viewport
 Divs A thru G.

```
    <section>
        -->  [A][B][    C   ][D]
        |    [                 ]
        |    [                 ]
height--|    [        E        ] 
        |    [                 ]
        |    [                 ]
        |    [         F           ]
        -->  [G]
        ...
        [ Z ]
    </section>
```

So I guess there may be a trick to find only the left most divs with the same smallest left position and then retrieve the heights from each of those items.   I want to select only a A - G height not A-Z height.  Is there a more accurate or standard way to do this even if the left position doesn't match precisely?

```
var gatherHeight = 0;
var sectionLeft = $("section").position().left;
$("section > div:nth-child(-n+7)").each(function() {
  if ($(this).position().left == sectionLeft)
  {
     gatherHeight += $(this).height();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To my understand the way jQuery each fucntion works is you pass an array of elements that you want to loop through as a parameter like so,

**jQuery**

```
var height = 0;
var elements = $('.elements');

$.each(elements,function(key,value) {

   height += $(this).height();
});
```

**Pure JS**

```
var height = 0;

var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.elements');

for(var i = 0;i < elements.length;i++) {

    height += elements[i].offsetHeight();
}
```

**UPDATE**

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <div class="parent in-viewport">
        <div class="child">

        </div>
        <div class="child">

        </div>
        <div class="child">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent out-viewport">
        <div class="child">

        </div>
        <div class="child">

        </div>
        <div class="child">

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**jQuery**

```
var height = 0;
var parents = $('.in-viewport');

$.each(parents,function(key,value) {

   height += $(this).height();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I see that but I actually need to get the height of not all the elements.  Only the ones on the left.  Like if they are floating divs then as you adjust the width that height thingy changes for a set of floating divs?

Comment: why dont you give the related elements (A to G) a css class? that way you can just do `$('.myClass')` to select all of them, then iterate through them using each?

Comment: I agree with @shxfree, the selector you're using is really slow and as you're noticing hard to work with, instead apply a class to the elements that you need to be selected and select that class with jQuery and iterate through them.

Comment: I am actually trying to replace all those elements with a placeholder.  The height can not equal to summation of the heights of the individual elements for that range.  It must equal the height of the entire set as if it were only one big div. Get it?

Comment: Are you using a grid system? If so calculate the row's height instead of the column. If you're not using a grid system wrap every four elements in a parent element and then select the parents and calculate the height of the parents as it's height will be based of the highest element inside of it. I'll throw together a couple line of codes and put them in my answer.

Comment: No. They have to be floating divs, no grid, no table, no bootstrap css.  I can just stick these selected span items into a new div and get that divs height, then empty that div after fixing the height.  But that's two steps and slowish.